# Avoid Redrawing of page element (ListView) Windows 8 HTML5 JS

Tags: javascript, html, listview, windows-8

Is there is a way to avoid redrawing of page elements(List View) is often visible during the transition from and to snapped view and when panning large hubs quickly?

[image]

Comment: Please can you rephrase your question? Split it up into several sentences. Your title is clear, but the content isn't.

Comment: @ Jodes : Cool here is the detailed explanation of what i'm trying to achieve... There are around 300+ Items in a page. When it is loading I can see redrawing of those items when panning it using scroll bar or changing the view to snap and come back, you can see that on the left side of the image i attached. I don't want that to  happen i want the element to get loaded smoothly.